Задача на вычисление площади прямоугольника из заборов
Дано n-ое кол-во заборов с одинаковым расстоянием друг от друга - 1, каждый из которых расположен на одной линии, и имеет разную длину. Нужно вычислить максимально возможную площадь образованного прямоугольника из заборов. Притом можно не использовать забор полностью, но нельзя его удлинять. Есть следующее решение:
def max_rectangle_area(length):
    n = len(length)
    max_area = 0
    for i in range(0, n):
        for j in  range(i+1, n):
            fence = length[i]
            fence_2 = length[j]
            if fence >= fence_2:
                area = fence_2*(j-i)
            else:
                area = fence*(j-i)
            if area > max_area:
                max_area = area

    return max_area


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Введите длину каждого забора через пробел:')
    fences = [int(x) for x in input().split(' ')]
    print(max_rectangle_area(fences))

Вопрос: как можно его улучшить/изменить, чтобы минимизировать использование памяти?
upd: Примерное изображение для наглядности.

Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами, размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Всем спасибо, оказывается много кушал банальный
print('Введите длину каждого забора через пробел:')


Ну таки да. Но все подумали, что так задачка поставлена и без этого никуда ))

Вот этот код, как и Ваш у меня на ноуте работает мгновенно! Оба! Никакие памяти никто не ест. Даже измерить ничего нельзя - просто нет на это времени, всё уже заканчивается. Я это место в задании до сих пор понять не могу. О том, насколько код этой готовой консольной утилитки "лучше", судите сами (жуткий input() и обработку результатов ввода я не менял):
import os

def max_rectangle_area(length):
    stack = []
    max_area = 0
    index = 0

    while index < len(length):
        if not stack or length[stack[-1]] <= length[index]:
            stack.append(index)
            index += 1
        else:
            top_of_stack = stack.pop()
            area = (length[top_of_stack] * ((index - stack[-1] - 1) if stack else index))
            max_area = max(max_area, area)

    while stack:
        top_of_stack = stack.pop()
        area = (length[top_of_stack] * ((index - stack[-1] - 1) if stack else index))
        max_area = max(max_area, area)

    return max_area

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Введите длину каждого забора через пробел:')
    fences = [int(x) for x in input().split(' ')]
    print(max_rectangle_area(fences))

os.system("pause")


Наверное. Одна из бесполезных на удивление загадочных конструкций, далёких от жизни и от программирования. В этой истории с идеями мне помогал приятель, я не настолько умный. Меня, как системщика и программиста, в этой задаче интересовала не задача , а утверждения о каких-то там памятях, медленностях и оптимизациях. Пусть автор разбирается с "идеями", если хочет. :-)))

Ну, вы меня поняли... Оптимизация кода - это бонус, просили в задании, я передал просьбу. Не моя заслуга. Мой интерес был - проверить сказки о расходе памяти и скорости. Сказки.
